# Stylling issues in jfx with Scrollpane

Tags: java, css, javafx, scrollpane

I have added a Label to the VBox which is further wrapped by Scrollpane. On doing so, my styling of Label is not working.

I have got a code here. It works fine when i remove the scrollpane.

```
package javasocket;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;

public class Controller {

    VBox msg_vbox = new VBox();

    @FXML
    ScrollPane scrlpane;

    @FXML
    TextField message;

    @FXML
    protected void sendMessage() {

        Label set_text = new Label();

        set_text.setText("Server Says: \n" + message.getText());


        set_text.setStyle("-fx-padding:10;-fx-margin:10;"
                + "-fx-background-color:teal;"
                + "    -fx-background-insets: 5;"
                + "-fx-font-size:15;"
                + "-fx-background-radius: 3;");
        set_text.setPrefSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.compare(0, 500));
               set_text.setWrapText(true);
        set_text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFY);
        msg_vbox.getChildren().addAll(set_text);
        scrlpane.setContent(msg_vbox);
        message.setText("");

    }

    @FXML
    protected void check_key(KeyEvent ae) {

        if (ae.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is. [image]

Comment: `-fx-margin` is not a CSS property of `Label`. Furhermore I recommend using `Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` instead of calculating the same value of using `Double.compare(0, 500)`. The real issue here is setting `prefWidth` to `Double.MAX_VALUE` though... Probably you want something like setting `maxWidth` for the `Label` to `Double.MAX_VALUE` and setting `fitToWidth` for the `ScrollPane` to `true` (avoiding a horizontal scrollbar by setting the content width to the width of the viewport).

Comment: Thank you very much @fabian. I appreciate that. Can i get clue on Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer myself. And special thanks to Fabian.

```
package javasocket;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;

public class Controller {

    VBox msg_vbox = new VBox();

    @FXML
    ScrollPane scrlpane;

    @FXML
    TextField message;

    @FXML
    protected void sendMessage() {

        //new label text with message.
        Label set_text = new Label();
        set_text.setText("Server Says: \n" + message.getText());
        set_text.setStyle("-fx-padding:10;"
                +"-fx-width:100%;"
                + "-fx-background-color:teal;"
                + "    -fx-background-insets: 5;"
                + "-fx-font-size:15;"
                + "-fx-background-radius: 3;");

        set_text.setPrefSize(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        set_text.setWrapText(true);
        set_text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFY);
        set_text.setPrefWidth(600);


        //VBox wrapper
        msg_vbox.getChildren().addAll(set_text);
        msg_vbox.setPrefWidth(600);

        //Further wrapped by ScrollPane
        scrlpane.fitToHeightProperty();
        scrlpane.setContent(msg_vbox);
        scrlpane.vvalueProperty().bind(msg_vbox.heightProperty()); //sets the scroll view to new element.
        message.setText("");



    }

    @FXML
    protected void check_key(KeyEvent ae) {

        if (ae.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    }
}
```